# Change the LineWidth in some parts of a plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an ECG signal and some special points of it calculated.

[image]

I want to have thicker LineWidth between those points (each pair). I did a sample with brush.

Here are my variables,

```
signal % the ECG signal
t      % time 
Q      % location of red points 
T      % location of yellow points
```

Four of these pairs are visible in picture, but there are more.

Is it possible without `loop _ hold on`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `hold on` and plot the data again on the region of interest:

```
% Some dummy data
x = 0:0.01:10;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)

% Data that we want emphasized
% You can also select a subset of your existing data
x_start = 2;
x_end = 4;
x_thick_line = x_start:0.01:x_end;
y_thick_line = sin(x_thick_line);

% Plot over the existing plot with thicker line
hold on
plot([x_start x_end],[y_thick_line(1) y_thick_line(end)],'ro',...
      x_thick_line,y_thick_line,'Color','r','LineWidth',6')
```

This gives the following result in Octave, should be the same in MATLAB:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Actually I have lots of them! 4 can be seen in the picture. I'm after something to plot without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should plot that function three times (assuming a..b shall be styled differently):

- 0..a - standard settings
- a..b - use alternate color / line_width / ...
- b..end